# Can't access cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a javascript like following on one page where I am setting cookies named "province" ,

```
document.cookie = 'province=' + $(elem).text() + '; expires=Fri, 3 Dec 2014 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

And I am trying to access cookie named "province" on other page like following

```
    function re() {
        var cn = getCookie("province");
        alert(cn);
        window.location = "lp.aspx?"+cn;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

But I am unable to access it in another page. Even though I am able to access it on page where I am setting cookies.

Any help will be appreciated

And yes the re() function is executing on button click and try is no exception

Comment: Is the other page on a different domain?

Comment: no it's in same application same domain\

Comment: You have to escape value of cookie on write and unescape - on read

Comment: @hindmost what do mean by escape and unescape?

Comment: @xyz [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) | [alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Comment: @hindmost can you please let me know how to use escape unescape cookies as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple is to use jquery

```
  $.cookie
```